# Audit Request for Complete List of Recognized Filename Extensions in FFMPEG FFPROBE FFPLAY

Tags: filenames, file-extension, file-types, mime-types

*I understand FFMPEG has a list of supported codecs and some users will be tempted to dismissively handwave my request by telling me to do my own research on codecs.  Those responses will be treated dismissively in kind.*

**I am looking for** a complete list of filename extensions that FFMPEG and FFPROBE and FFPLAY will automatically recognize on input (and associate to a CODEC), and automatically generate on output (as a default filetype extension), without user specification.

The purpose of this request is to conduct a survey of known and/or popular file extensions in use by multimedia filenames, as supported by modern software.  So, no cheating please.

If someone knows where to locate these filetype extensions in FFMPEG and FFPROBE and FFPLAY so they can be extracted as text into a tidy list, or who is willing to put forth the effort to these ends, your insight would be greatly appreciated.  Categorized by Video and Audio (or video+audio) codec or container would be wonderful.

*I can achieve my own ends in media player software like VLC, MPV, MPC by looking at their Windows Installer list of supported filetype associations.  FFMPEG doesn't make its list of supported filetype associations as readily apparent.*

Comment: Surely you can find the answers you're looking for in the source code: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg

Comment: Well, maybe you can, but I could not. And apparently nobody else can either or this question would have been answered readily and with enthusiasm.